# selectmenu jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In an HTML page:

```
<select  id="countryDiv" class="selectmenu">
      <option value="-1~-1"  selected="selected" >Country</option>
</select>
```

`class="selectmenu"` is working fine. But when I append the same code from a JavaScript file the element with the `selectmenu` class is not working.

For example, in the following block the `countryBlock` is appended to the HTML page but the element with the `selectmenu` class is not working:

```
var cnt='<div class="leftalign selectBox-wrap ele-width-23 mrg-right-5">
         <select name="country" id="countryDiv" class="selectmenu" >
        ' + contOptions + ' </select> </div> ';
$("#countryBlock").html(cnt);
```

Comment: Please define "not working" ? If you mean you can't attach an event to that element, it is most probably normal. You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to trigger dynamically generated elements. Please note that ideally delgegation should apply to the closest static parent for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

js or jquery won't work on html that is generated by the jquery .. so if you are performing any operation on selectmenu class like

```
$(".selectmenu").select(function (){
 // code here
});
```

change to this .

```
$('.selectmenu').on('select', function () {
 // code here
}
```

Comment: both your examples don't use event delegation that would indeed solve the problem you're addressing

Comment: this also won't work, both are same. Event delegation syntax is different.